# How to Override Content-Security-Policy of Site A while using nginx proxy_pass on Site B for serving content?

Tags: security, nginx, proxy, content-security-policy

Is there a way to override Content-Security-Policy set by the domain/site A while i am using nginx proxy_pass on Site B.

```
Site A defined Content-Security-Policy on their domain.
Site B acts as a reverse proxy for site A.
```

How can i override Content-Security-Policy while serve content from site B ?

how can i achieve this in nginx proxy pass ?

my current nginx server block looks like this

```
server {
server_name  proxy-domain.com.;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://www.target-site.com/;
      proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding ""; 
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;   
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

i have tried adding

add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'

e.g.

```
server {
server_name  proxy-domain.com.;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://www.target-site.com/;
      proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding ""; 
      proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;   
      proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
}
```

but if i check headers of site B, then it shows modified Content-Security-Policy of site B but the content from other sources does not gets loaded., only headers are set.

why is that ?

update:
when i check headers i get 2 Content-Security-Policy headers , first are set by site A and then later one Content-Security-Policy headers set be my i.e. site B.

e.g.

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' apis.google.com www.google.com;
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.cloudflare.com;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem seems similar to the [Nginx as reverse Proxy, remove X-Frame-Options header](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,246143,246154#msg-246154) thread on the Nginx mailing list.  That solution was [proxy_hide_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_hide_header)

> By default, nginx does not pass the header fields “Date”, “Server”,
>   “X-Pad”, and “X-Accel-...” from the response of a proxied server to a
>   client. The proxy_hide_header directive sets additional fields that
>   will not be passed. If, on the contrary, the passing of fields needs
>   to be permitted, the proxy_pass_header directive can be used.

Comment: I have a similar issue, I tried your answer but either I'm doing it wrong or it is a bit different. Do you mind elaborating? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71841384/forward-http-request-through-nginx-using-subdomain-to-a-specific-port-violates-c/71864246)