# nginx reverse proxy content-security-policy not working

Tags: nginx, https, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt

ive installed Firefly via dockerhub on my cloud vm, all is working fine. Iam now trying to access it via https (lets encrypt is setup correctly, I can reach the base domain via https just fine.)

Firefly runs as a docker under port :90. Its accessible and fully functional.
But whenever I try to access it via https, certain CSP headers (e.g base-uri and form-action) are not set.

Current nginx.conf excerpts (http:// is infront of the domain, but sof doesnt let me include it):

```
location /firefly/ { proxy_pass mydomain.org:90[1]/; }
```

ive tried to include in the above

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "form-action 'self'; base-uri 'self' ";
```

or

```
proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy "form-action 'self'; base-uri 'self' ";
```

I have also tried the same commands with a '*' instead of 'self'.

I keep getting mydomain.org:90 resource was blocked form-action and base-uri.

Error:
[browser errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKS1y.png)
Send Headers:
[double csp?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FR0X.png)

Does anyone know, what I am doing wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Override Content-Security-Policy of Site A while using nginx proxy\_pass on Site B for serving content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300111/how-to-override-content-security-policy-of-site-a-while-using-nginx-proxy-pass-o)