# content security policy (csp) issue for subdomain with nginx as reverse proxy and node express as backand

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, content-security-policy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an issue with content security policy headers. Scripts and styles are blocked.

It seams that nginx is overloading my express headers.

I tried a lot and my last state is this.

nginx server block

```
...
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
}
....
```

express setup (domain name is changed to example.com)

```
const express = require('express');
const lusca = require('lusca');
const app = express();
...
app.use(lusca.xframe('SAMEORIGIN'));
app.use(lusca.xssProtection(true));
app.use(
  lusca.csp({
    policy: {
      "default-src": "'self' *.example.com",
      "img-src": "*"
    }
  })
);
...
```

In the browser console I get this:

```
content security policy the page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at ("default-src")
content security policy the page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at ("script-src")
content security policy the page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at ("style-src")
```

In broswsers answer field (csp is twice!):

```
content-security-policy: default-src 'self' *.example.com; img-src *
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self';
```

Does anyone have an idea why this configuration is not working? Or how to tell nginx to use express's headers and hold down the own?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Override Content-Security-Policy of Site A while using nginx proxy\_pass on Site B for serving content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33300111/how-to-override-content-security-policy-of-site-a-while-using-nginx-proxy-pass-o)

Comment: Thanks for the link. See my answer. It's a different solution to the suggested post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `proxy_pass_header` to the nginx server block:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header x-real-ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

    // THIS DIRECTIVE SOLVED IT
    proxy_pass_header content-security-policy;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain what happened and how did you find that proxy_pass_header solve your problem? I tried your solution, but it doesn't work